# Display numbers as a mutliple of (10^3)^n ( number format)

Tags: python, matplotlib, format, numbers

I have a numpy array of data. These data are tensions. So I want them to be in kilovolts `(10^3)^1`, Volts `(10^3)^0`, millivolts `(10^3)^-1`, microvolts `(10^3)^-2`.

In Excel I used to format numbers as custom and `"##0,0E+0"` but I don't want to use Excel any more.

I tried to do this in Python:

```
plt.ticklabel_format(axis = 'y', style = 'sci', scilimits = (0,0))
```

with matplotlib.
But it displays numbers like multiples of `10^(-5)` or `10^(-4)` sometimes. I want it to display these numbers like `10*10(-6)` or `100*10^(-6)`.

Here is the full code :

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import csv 
import pandas as pd
from scipy import fftpack
import os
from pathlib import Path



def slice_temps(donnees, temps_debut, temps_fin): 
    """
    

    Parameters
    ----------
    donnees : numpy array
        Les donnees dont on veut seulement une partie du temps 
    temps_debut : float
        La borne inférieur de la partie du temps qu'on veut 
    temps_fin : float
        La borne supérieur de la partie du temps qu'on veut 

    Returns
    -------
    numpy array
        Les donnees mais seulement sur une partie du temps. (Il y a toutes les données (phase, 1F, courant...etc))

    """
    if temps_debut < donnees[0,3] or temps_fin > donnees[len(donnees[:,3])-1,3] or temps_debut > temps_fin :
        print("Slice : Les bornes indiquees ne sont pas bonnes. Le temps est comrpis entre (", donnees[0,3],  ",", donnees[len(donnees[:,3])-1,3], ") s")
        return np.empty(np.shape(donnees))
    else : 
        i_temps_debut, = np.where(np.isclose(donnees[:,3], temps_debut))
        i_temps_fin, = np.where(np.isclose(donnees[:,3], temps_fin))
        return donnees[i_temps_debut[0]:i_temps_fin[0],:]
    
    


def suppression_temps(donnees, temps_debut_suppression, temps_fin_suppression):
    """
    Permets de supprimer les données entre deux temps. Cette fonction renvoie un numpy array sans la partie non désirée. 

    Parameters
    ----------
    donnees : TYPE
        DESCRIPTION.
    temps_debut_suppression : TYPE
        DESCRIPTION.
    temps_fin_suppression : TYPE
        DESCRIPTION.

    Returns
    -------
    TYPE
        DESCRIPTION.

    """
    if temps_debut_suppression < donnees[0,3] or temps_fin_suppression > donnees[len(donnees[:,3])-1,3] or temps_debut_suppression > temps_fin_suppression :
        print("Suppression : Les bornes indiquees ne sont pas bonnes. Le temps est comrpis entre (", donnees[0,3],  ",", donnees[len(donnees[:,3])-1,3], ") s")
        return np.empty(np.shape(donnees))
    else :
        i_temps_debut_suppression, = np.where(np.isclose(donnees[:,3], temps_debut_suppression))
        i_temps_fin_suppression, = np.where(np.isclose(donnees[:,3], temps_fin_suppression))
        
        premiere_partie = donnees[:i_temps_debut_suppression[0],:]
        seconde_partie = donnees[i_temps_fin_suppression[0]:,:]
        return np.concatenate((premiere_partie , seconde_partie))







#Changer simplement le path avec celui du fichier souhaité ici : 

windows_path = r"H:\2024_02_09\2024_02_09_ScanTime_ALN-2035_29deg_0mA_mod9800Htz35mA-LaserOFF-VentilateurOFF.csv"
universal_path = Path(windows_path)


data = pd.read_csv(universal_path , sep = ';'  , skiprows = 1,  encoding = 'ISO-8859-1', engine = 'python' ) 
data.head()
donnees = np.char.replace(data.to_numpy(dtype = str), ',', '.').astype(float)

#  data.to_numpy(dtype = str) transforme pandas.dataframe en numpy.array
#  np.char.replace(, ',', '.') remplace virgules par des points dans les strings
#  .astype(float) convertie les strings en float



plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
plt.grid()
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(['{:,.0f}'.format(x*1e6)  + "*10(-6)" for x in plt.gca().get_yticks()])
plt.scatter(donnees[:,3], donnees[:,7], s = 1)
plt.xlabel("Temps(s)")
plt.ylabel("Signal microphones (V)")
plt.title("Signal du microphone laser ON et ventilateur ON. \n Le laser est sur un pic de signal ( 0.566A ) et son intensité est constante.\n Laser à 29°C, aucun débit.\n Temps de pose de 8 minutes ")
plt.show()

#%%
#Selection en temps et calcul de moyenne / ecart-type


donnees_slice = slice_temps(donnees, 40468, 41041 )


plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
plt.grid()
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(['{:,.0f}'.format(x*1e6)  + "*10(-6)" for x in plt.gca().get_yticks()])
plt.scatter(donnees_slice[:,3], donnees_slice[:,7])
plt.xlabel("Temps(s)")
plt.ylabel("Signal microphones (V)")
plt.title(f'Signal du microphone laser OFF et ventilateur OFF. \n Le laser est sur un pic de signal ( 0.566A ) et son intensité est constante.\n Laser à 29°C, aucun débit. Temps de pose de 9 minutes \n Moyenne = {np.mean(donnees_slice[:,6])} Ecart-type = {np.std(donnees_slice[:,6])} \n RSB = {np.mean(donnees_slice[:,6]) / np.std(donnees_slice[:,6])}')
plt.show()

#%% On supprime les bruits trop importants(exemple : quelqu'un parle pendant l'acquisition de données, bruit de porte ...etc)


supr_1 = suppression_temps(donnees, 40529, 40568)
supr_2 = suppression_temps(supr_1, 40738, 40807)


plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
plt.grid()
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(['{:,.0f}'.format(x*1e6)  + "*10(-6)" for x in plt.gca().get_yticks()])
plt.scatter(supr_2[:,3], supr_2[:,7])
plt.xlabel("Temps(s)")
plt.ylabel("Signal microphones (V)")
plt.title(f'Signal du microphone laser OFF et ventilateur OFF. \n Le laser est sur un pic de signal ( 0.566A ) et son intensité est constante.\n Laser à 29°C, aucun débit. Temps de pose de 9 minutes \n Moyenne = {np.mean(supr_2[:,6])} Ecart-type = {np.std(supr_2[:,6])} \n RSB = {np.mean(supr_2[:,6]) / np.std(supr_2[:,6])}')
plt.show()
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

First solution:

```
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(['{:,.0f}'.format(x*1e6)  + "*10(-6)" for x in plt.gca().get_yticks()])
```

Update for first solution to avoid warning "UserWarning: FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator":

```
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.FixedLocator(plt.gca().get_yticks()))
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(['{:,.0f}'.format(x*1e6)  + "*10(-6)" for x in plt.gca().get_yticks()])
```

Second solution that I decided to add after my fellow user JohanC has suggested FuncFormatter

After importing:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
```

you can also use:

```
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: "{:,.0f}*10(-6)".format(x * 1e6)))
```

I think this version is harder but you can learn more about FuncFormatter in these two links:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter

&

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.8.2/lib/matplotlib/ticker.py#L304-L329

**Edit:** you can achieve what you want in the comments by implementing a function to custom format your data. Here is an example, you will probably need to add more or adjust for what you have in mind:

```
def formatter(x, pos):
    if abs(x) >= 1e-3:
        return "{:,.0f} * 10^(-3)".format(x * 1e3)
    elif abs(x) >= 1e-4 and abs(x) < 1e-3:
        return "{:,.0f} * 10^(-6)".format(x * 1e4)
    elif abs(x) >= 1e-5 and abs(x) < 1e-4:
        return "{:,.0f} * 10^(-9)".format(x * 1e5)
    elif abs(x) >= 1e-6 and abs(x) < 1e-5:
        return "{:,.0f} * 10^(-12)".format(x * 1e6)
    # Add more depending on what you want to include
    else:
        return "{:,.0f}".format(x)
```

then use this edited version of the function formatter line

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(formatter))
```

Note that the y-labels may not be able to fit all kinds of values, for example it could include y-ticks for 10(-3) and smaller points would reside between the smallest 10(-3) value and 0.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: Instead of `set_yticklabels()` it would be much better to use a [tick formatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/tick-formatters.html), e.g. a [FuncFormatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter).

Comment: @Cem Koçak
It works but first the console says "UserWarning: FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator
  plt.gca().set_yticklabels(['{:,.0f}'.format(x*1e6)  + "*10(-6)" for x in plt.gca().get_yticks()])" and secondly this format is too too large i can't see it in the separate window that display graphics unless i fully extend it. 
How can i solve this ?

Comment: @Camille , Hmm I dont get that warning when I run it on my end, can you include your data in your answer or DM me your data(preferably the entire code you have run that resulted in the warning),

Comment: @CemKoçak I don't know how to DM you my data ? I can't find any DM feature on this website. 
I added the entire code on my initial message.

Comment: @Camille have you also tried the second solution I gave btw ?

Comment: @Camille , Ok the updated first solution and the second solution doesnt give you warnings. Please let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: @CemKoçak Yes i tried the second seloution. It works well, thank you very much. 
However, when i have for exemple 20 mV. It shows it as 20 000 *10^(-6) Volt. But i wanted to show it as 20 * 10^(-3) Volt. 
So in a single plot, if i have a 20mV and a 0.4mV for example. I want it to display the first number as 20*10^(-3)V, and the second as 400*10^(-6)V. How could i do this pls ?